The “Get more details” links and “Password recovery page” for the “I lost my password” option on Area 51 contact form leads to error page
This question is not the same like my recent question.
In the contact form for Area 51, we click “Account Issue—> I lost my password” option, a pop-up will be shown:



Click “Get more details” or “Password Recovery Page” and it leads us to this error page.



Can the error page be fixed?
Edit: I have clicked the “Contact us” button shown on that error page and reported this issue.
Like what @Shadow said, not only “password recovery page” is broken, but all the links in the Area 51 Contact form is broken, they lead to error page or “FAQ” with no expected results.

It's much bigger. The whole help center and infrastructure of Area51 is ancient, and 1000 miles behind SE actual sites. The bug is that the "contact us" is still there, it should redirect here, with some flag on the URL saying "user arrived from Area51". E.g. you might notice all links in the contact page are broken, i.e. leading either to Not Found as in this case, or to the "faq" of Area51 that does not contain the topics you expect to see.

@ShadowWizard Looks like this issue is very hard to be fixed…
